# How can I make this code more efficient (Objective C)?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'm just starting out in Objective-C, and have created an iOS program that I'd like to improve upon.  In it, I've got two code blocks:

```
if ([stringTest isEqualToString:@"apple"]){
    numTest=0;
}else if (([stringTest isEqualToString:@"orange"])||([stringTest isEqualToString:@"lemon"])){
    numTest=1;
}else if ([stringTest isEqualToString:@"pumpkin"]){
    numTest=2;   // and so on...
```

And then the reverse:

```
  if (numTest==0){
        stringTest=@"apple";
    } else if (numTest==1){
        stringTest=@"orange/lemon";
    } else if (numTest==2){
        stringTest=@"pumpkin";  // and so on...
```

As these lists actually involve many more items, I'm sure there's a much better way to do this.  Any suggestions would be very much appreciated.  Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest setting up NSDictionaries that map the strings to numbers and numbers to strings. With the new object literal syntax:

```
NSDictionary* numberLookup = @{@"apple": @0, @"orange", @1, @"lemon", @2, @"pumpkin": @3};
numTest = [numberLookup objectForKey:stringTest];

NSDictionary* stringLookup = @{@0, @"apple", @1, "orange/lemon", .....
stringTest = [stringLookup objectForKey:numTest];
```

The literal syntax for NSDictionary is `@{key: value, ...}`. Note the use of @ symbols preceeding the numeric values; NSDictionary expects all keys and values to be objects. `@1` is equivalent to `[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]`. And The dictionary literal syntax is similar to `[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@0, @"apple", ..., nil]`.

#### Edit: generating the second dictionary from the first

```
// Map strings to numbers
NSDictionary* numberLookup = @{@"apple": @0, ...};

// Map numbers to strings
NSMutableDictionary* stringLookup = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:numberLookup.count];
for (str in numberLookup) {
    id num = [numberLookup objectForKey:str];
    if ([stringLookup objectForKey:num]) {
        NSString* currentStr = [stringLookup objectForKey:num];
        [stringLookup setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", currentStr, str] forKey:num]
    } else {
        [stringLookup setObject:str forKey:num];
    }
}
```

Comment: True, but only the first should be hardcoded. The second should be generated automatically from the first. This will be more robust.

Comment: Yes, it would be ideal for the second to be generated from the first. In this case you would need a bit of special logic though to combine the orange and lemon cases, but it would be doable.

Comment: Terrific, thanks for this—definitely a step forward.  Yes, the fact that my numbers and strings don't have a "one-to-one" relationship is a complication... Using NSDictionary terminology, I suppose I've got cases where several keys that correspond to the same value.

Comment: OK, the edit's great.  It looks like it's showing me lots of important NSDictionary methods too.  In general, are NSMutableDictionaries good form to use?  (I ask because I've come across "don't use NSMutableString or NSMutableArray" comments before.)

Comment: I would say that if you want to go this route, it would be fine to use a mutable dictionary. As @Nate Chandler mentioned in his answer, the best practice would be to only create both of these dictionaries once and persist them as static variables, or class members, etc.

Answer (score 1):

For obtaining a number for a string, @esker is correct that an `NSDictionary` should be used.  This dictionary, however, should only be generated once, assuming that it is used multiple times:

```
static NSDictionary *numberForFruit = nil;
if (!numberForFruit) {
    NSUInteger numberOfStrings = 4;
    NSMutableDictionary *mutableNumberForFruit = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:numberOfStrings];
    #define addNumberForFruitToMutableNumberForFruit(number,fruit) [mutableNumberForFruit setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:number] forKey:@#fruit];
    addNumberForFruitToMutableNumberForFruit(0, apple);
    addNumberForFruitToMutableNumberForFruit(1, orange);
    addNumberForFruitToMutableNumberForFruit(1, lemon);
    addNumberForFruitToMutableNumberForFruit(2, pumpkin);
    numberForFruit = [mutableNumberForFruit copy];
}
```

Going the other direction, however, it would be much better to use a switch statement:

```
switch (numTest) {
    case 0: {
        strings = @[@"Apple"];
    } break;
    case 1: {
        strings = @[@"Orange", @"Lemon"];
    } break;
    case 2: {
        strings = @[@"Pumpkin"];
    } break;
}
```

Comment: Good idea to map the numbers to arrays of strings, so the caller takes responsibility for combining the values with the desired formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you'd use this for but I guess you could also use enumeration if your numbers are sequential:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    enum fruits 
    { 
        apple = 0, 
        banana, 
        orange 
    };

    NSLog(@"Apple is: %d", apple);
    NSLog(@"Banana is: %d", banana);
    NSLog(@"Orange is: %d", orange);

    return 0;
}
```

Output would be:

```
2012-10-30 21:40:45.758 TestEnum[1274:403] Apple is: 0
2012-10-30 21:40:45.761 TestEnum[1274:403] Banana is: 1
2012-10-30 21:40:45.762 TestEnum[1274:403] Orange is: 2
```

Note, the order you specify the enumeration labels matter. In this case, I told "apple" to start from 0.

I could very well tell "apple" to start from 5 and if I were to do this, "banana" would become 6 instead of 1 because enumeration is sequential, the next label will take on a value +1 from the previous label.

Sorry I don't know what the technical name for the labels are, I call them labels :P